# If my goal is to reduce execution time, when (and how) is it OK to remove function wrappers?

Tags: php, performance, function

I have been a part of several projects where reducing the execution time of a script was a major goal.  Along with rewriting loops, I have found that removing function wrappers (and introducing plenty of duplicate code) can significantly improve execution time.  However, when I start doing this I feel that I am creating a bad situation for myself later.  What are some good guidelines to follow when removing functions and function calls?

Some thoughts:

- Keep a copy of the original code with functions included
- document sections where functions were remove and code was copied-and-pasted.

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate to programmers.stackexchange

Comment: I think your right, can the question be moved to programmers.stackexchange ?

Comment: Try http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91381/how-to-migrate-question-to-programmers-stackexchange-com

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to move my own question

Comment: Flag to moderator attention